# Exchanging UK driving licence for Irish licence after 16 months of residency?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, driving-license, ireland, car-insurance

What happens if you exchange your UK licence for an Irish licence after living in Ireland for 16 months? I understand you need to exchange it within 12 months. I only bought a car 5 months ago. I also would like to know what happens to my UK-owned vehicle if I exchange my UK licence for an Irish one - can I still have that (registered to a UK address of a family member) or not? Do I have to sell it or transfer ownership?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if you exchange your UK licence for an Irish licence after living in Ireland for 16 months?

On taking up 'normal residence' in Ireland you must either exchange your driving licence or apply for a driving licence in Ireland. AFAIK, the latter now applies in your case.

Source: [National Driver Licence Service](https://www.ndls.ie/licensed-driver/exchange-my-uk-ni-licence.html)

> Can I still have my UK-owned vehicle (registered to a UK address of a family member) or not?

No. If you are the registered owner, you must have a permanent address in the UK. You need to [transfer ownership](https://www.gov.uk/sold-bought-vehicle). You should also inform your car insurance company.